# The shape of lightning

Tags: single-word-requests, shapes

Is there any word to describe something that has lightning/tree/vein like structure?

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that I'd prefer a word that emphasizes the random nature of these structures. Otherwise branching (as suggested by Harrold) seems fitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *branching structure* is commonly used in the graph theory to describe a type of hierarchy.

**Edit:** The best I could come up with after you edited your question is to describe it as *something*-shaped, for example *lightning-shaped*. No term that I can remember of apart from e.g. specific computational algorithms does incorporate the randomness.

**Second edit:** I have just remembered the word **stochastic** or **pedesis**, while the latter is another term for Brownian movement. Considering these terms, you may utilise something like *stochastic branching structure* if you need to appear appealing. That is my current limit, I am afraid. :-)

Comment: Stochastic is perfect, that's exactly the type of word I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: @Curious Little Guy I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 6):

What about the word ***dendritic***?

It comes from the Greek word for tree, and considering it is primarily used for natural entities such as [cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrite) in the body, and [dendritic solidification structures](http://www.msm.cam.ac.uk/phase-trans/dendrites.html), I think it encapsulates the random aspect that you are looking for beautifully.

Comment: +1 dendritic is a very good suggestion but stochastic is a better fit for naming a software class :)

Comment: @CuriousLittleGuy: Oops, I didn't realise you were after a word to describe an abstract entity. You're right, dendritic doesn't really fit; it's mainly used for physical, (often fractal-like) structures.

Comment: It's my fault anyway for not giving enough information in the first place. TBH I wasn't very sure what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

- informal: **zig-zag**,  **jagged**,  or **forked**
- formal/technical: **furcated** (like a fork), or **reticulate** (like a net)

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but I have a strong feeling that none of these suggestions capture the fractal-like(?) shape of lightning. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Also, being a Greek, I have a strong bias towards Greek-rooted words that I can understand better. (stochastic - στοχαστική and dendritic - δενδρική)

Comment: @Curious: I'm curious as to why _fractal_ isn't the word you are looking for.

Comment: My initial question was poorly written mostly because I wasn't sure what I was looking for. To indulge your curiosity I have created a web-crawler that uses some helper (model) classes to determine the crawling paths. One of these classes (the most efficient btw) is using a weighted semi-random approach to decide the next URL to crawl. RandomModel seemed a bit underestimating for the complexity of the algorithm behind it. Anyway, since the paths taken with this method resembled a lightning I shoot the question to see what could come out. StochasticModel seems better than FractalModel for this.

Comment: Also _fractal_ has Latin roots... (j/k)